# Fail catching a promises in react

Tags: json, reactjs, promise, axios

I've just started learning react and what I'm trying to do is set up a simple component that calls a specific API, passing an argument.

Axios: https://github.com/axios/axios
The API: https://dog.ceo/dog-api/

My code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Itemlist extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {items: [], breedName: ''}
        this.fetchSubBreeds = this.fetchSubBreeds.bind(this);
        this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    }

    fetchSubBreeds() {
        axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breed/' + this.state.breedName + '/list')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({items: response.data.message})
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({items: []});
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    updateInputValue(evt) {
        this.setState({breedName: evt.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <label for='breed'>Breed name: </label>
                <input type='text' name='breed' 
                    onBlur={() => this.fetchSubBreeds()} 
                    onChange={(evt) => this.updateInputValue(evt)}>
                </input>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.items.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item}</li>)}
                </ul>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Itemlist
```

When a breed exists I get the correct list of sub breeds, but when the params is wrong it seems like the catch function sleeps, because i get this error:

```
TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function
render

  34 |             onChange={(evt) => this.updateInputValue(evt)}>
  35 |         </input>
  36 |         <ul>
> 37 |             {this.state.items.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item}  </li>)}
  38 |         </ul>  
  39 |     </div>
  40 | );
```

API response on error: https://dog.ceo/api/breed/random/list

**What's the correct way to handle the response error?**

Comment: Try `.then(response, error)` instead of `.then(response).catch(error)`.

Comment: @Aaron Isn't that the same?

Comment: It's not the same but in this case it wouldn't have made any difference... Govind figured it out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the API still responds with a status code of 200 (which means the success in HTTP land) regardless of whether or not you provide a valid breed. Since the API server responds with a success code the catch statement is never called. Therefore you need to do the checking in the `then` statement instead of the `catch`. Parse the response and check to see if the status property is equal to "error".

```
fetchSubBreeds() {
    axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breed/' + this.state.breedName + '/list')
    .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.status==="error"){
           return console.log("breed doesn't exists"); //or whatever logic
        } else {
            this.setState({items: response.data.message})
        }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({items: []});
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So the .catch() is fired only on 404 response code?

Comment: Catch statements are fired when an error is thrown. It's up to you or the developers of the libraries you are using on how they choose to handle errors. In the case of Axios, it will trigger the catch statement whenever the response code is a failing code i.e. >=400.